# ContentBySearchWebPart and search results

Tags: 2013, search, search-results

I am working with Sharepoint 2013 and I have multiple ContentBySearchWebParts on the page (in master page actually). It works ok up until I try that along with a search (SearchBoxScriptWebPart). I set different Query Group Names for each ContentBySearchWebParts, but it still apparently uses the searched term from SearchBoxScriptWebPart.

To illustrate:

1. I have ContentBySearchWebPart that is configured to show results with 'AAA' enterprise metedata
2. Another ContentBySearchWebPart that displays items with 'BBB'
3. I search for 'CCC' in SearchBoxScriptWebPart
4. On the results page I see results for 'CCC' but my two ContentBySearchWebParts are empty. If I manually searched for 'BBB', the ContentBySearchWebPart WOULD also display the correct results.

Anyone can shed some light on this for me? Thanks!

Comment: I cant follow what you are trying to do - can you share a screenshot of your problem?

Comment: Sure, hope [this](http://imgur.com/vL4H1xa) image makes it more clear.

Comment: Do you mean that the ContentBySearch WebParts are only updated when you initially hit the page? It wont get updated when you use the search box on the same page. Note the ?k parameter and the #k hash in the url.

Comment: Yeah, esentially it does not get updated, but it should. It is using the client side rendering (display templates etc.). Also, I am NOT using Minimal Download Strategy for the page. So how should I go about making sure those ContentBySearchWebParts are updated. As mentined before, it only breaks when SearchBoxScriptWebPart is involved, works everywhere else.